# Using a Skeleton in Mercurial for multiple similar projects

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have multiple modules, each in their own repository.
Then there's a skeleton, which has some basic code that's common for all clients, with subrepos of some modules that are always included.

What is the best way to use this set-up on a new client?

The problem I'm currently experiencing is:
- if I clone the skeleton and then add something in the skeleton and push it to the server, the skeleton gets updated.

If I have a repository per project for the client in which I clone the skeleton, the same thing happens: the changes in the skeleton are pushed to the skeleton.

Now, I can probably fix this by cloning the skeleton and then immediately creating a new branch for the client in the skeleton, but I prefer if it has its own repository for the delivery to the server, instead of being a branch of the skeleton (which I want to use for skeleton versions, not projects).

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Are you wanting it as a starting-point, or as modules/packages which remain unchanged?

Comment: The skeleton should be the base of new projects, so a starting-point. Before cloning the skeleton, the developer should pull in changes in the subrepositories (the modules) so the skeleton is always up2date. In the future, we might need to branch off the skeleton for non-backwards compatible things, but we're not at that stage yet.

Comment: If you can possibly avoid changing parts of it, it becomes easier with subrepositories, but if you need to change parts of the skeleton you will run into issues. I still don't fully understand the details of your question.

Comment: Can't you just clone the skeleton and then change the default-push path in the clone to a new repository created for the client ? This way there will be no more link between the new clone and the skeleton repositories... I'm using this method myself each time I develop a new website : on my server, I clone a base repository and then remove the default-push in the `.hgrc`. This new repository is then used as the base for development.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the missing bit of information is that you can change the default push path after making a clone. When you run

```
$ hg clone http://hg.server/repos/skeleton client-a
```

to get a `client-a` clone from the `skeleton` repo, then Mercurial creates `client-a/.hg/hgrc` with

```
[paths]
default = http://hg.server/repos/skeleton
```

So `hg push` will now send changesets to that repository. You should instead make a new clone on the server:

```
$ hg clone skeleton client-a
```

and then make a clone of that on your machine:

```
$ hg clone http://hg.server/repos/client-a
```

Changes to the skeleton code will then no longer automatically propagate to the `skeleton` repo on the server.

An important down-side of this is that all your client repositories will be "compatible" This means that you can do this by accident:

```
$ cd client-a
$ hg pull http://hg.server/repos/client-b
```

This works since `client-a` and `client-b` share a common ancestor in the `skeleton` repository. For that reason, I would simply copy the skeleton files and adds them anew to each client repository:

```
$ unzip skeleton.zip
$ rm skeleton.zip
$ hg add
$ hg commit -m "Initialized repository for client-a"
```

Since the date and commit message will be different for each client, the repositories will become *unrelated* and `hg push` and `hg pull` will then error out if you try to mix changesets from different clients.